# I'm trying to make a square shape with an empty space inside something like a door, how could I improve this?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

How could I improve this code? I want to print a square of asterisks with an empty space in the middle something like a door :)

```
public class Figure {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= 7; j++){
                if(i == 3 && j == 3 || i == 3 && j == 4 ||  i == 3 && j == 5 || 
                   i == 4 && j == 3 || i == 4 && j == 4 ||  i == 4 && j == 5 ||
                   i == 5 && j == 3 || i == 5 && j == 4 ||  i == 5 && j == 5){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a square shape with an empty space inside something like a door